# Why am I getting zero results for multiple search strings using BeautifulSoup when tutorials always return embeded text no problem?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm beginning learning coding and can't understand why video tutorials always use a simple method of entering multiple search strings to return embedded tags within a tag and they get results, yet my len(query) always comes back with a big fat 0 when doing the same thing. I'm using nearly the exact same code. Ultimately for this post, let's say I want to return the URLS. They are behind "div" then "h3" and then "href" tags on this page. But for example, let's please just try to narrow down the "h3" text behind the "div" tags.

Example:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from selenium import webdriver

response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHnSLOMOPT11ORMDapNppzDKBYnWWP66O')

response
<python response: <Response [200]>

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

videos = soup.find_all('div')

len(videos)
<python response: 95>
```

For this I get 95 pings on the request for div tags. However when I add *any* second string to narrow down those for further HTML, I get 0 response back. Let's try adding the h3 tag. It should give a much lower  integer return, but I get zero.

```
 
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

from selenium import webdriver

response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHnSLOMOPT11ORMDapNppzDKBYnWWP66O')

response
<python response: <Response [200]>

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

videos = soup.find_all('div', 'h3')

len(videos)
<python response: 0>
```

What is taking me aback is tutorials and videos use the same simplistic <'query 1', '<query 2'> method in the videos, and they get search results that filter accordingly with each tags embedded text. I would be appreciative of code suggestions on filtering the embedded tags texts, as well as perhaps en explanation with what I may be doing incorrectly that these videos are doing right for the simplistic methods they demonstrate which hasn't worked for me..

I've even tried doing the same method on a simple WikiPedia page, but again more than one string get's a 0 response.

Comment: I don't suppose you can make a short dummy html sample that demonstrates the issue with only a few matches? It would make the question self-contained (complete).

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list as the first argument. It doesn't look very different, but it's definitely not the exact same thing:

```
videos = soup.find_all(['div', 'h3'])
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list

This is the function you are calling in the bad code:

```
find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

You are looking for name='div', attrs='h3', so 0 is the answer you should expect. This is the kind of thing you are actually telling it to looking for (which nobody would actually put in their html):

> <div class="h3">...</div>

full example demonstrating the proper syntax:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO

content = BytesIO(bytes("""<html>
<body>
  <h3><div id='first'>content</div></h3>
  <h3><div id='second'>content</div></h3>
  <h3><div id='third'>content</div></h3>
</body>
</html>
""", 'utf-8'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
videos = soup.find_all(['div', 'h3'])
print(len(videos))
```

output

> 6